# how to perform division on dynamic columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following columns in pandas

```
code    nozzle_1_cumsum   nozzle_2_cumsum    nozzle_sale_cumsum
123     10                10                 20
123     20                10                 10
123     10                10                 10
```

In above dataframe  `nozzle_1_cumsum & nozzle_2_cumsum` are dynamic columns, it could be `nozzle_1_cumsum, nozzle_2_cumsum, nozzle_3_cumsum etc` and `nozzle_sale_cumsum` is static column. What I want to do is generate 2 new columns as ratios.(nozzle_1_cumsum \ nozzle_sale_cumsum & nozzle_2_cumsum \ nozzle_sale_cumsum)

```
code    nozzle_1_cumsum   nozzle_2_cumsum    nozzle_sale_cumsum  nozzle_1_perc  nozzle_2_perc 
123     10                10                 20                  0.5            0.5
123     20                10                 10                  2              1
123     10                10                 10                  1              1
```

How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: `df.filter(regex='nozzle_\d+').div(df['nozzle_sale_cumsum'].values[:, None])`

Comment: It is giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a list of the columns you want to perform this action on, then loop through them creating the new columns each loop

```
import re
cols = [cols for cols in df.columns if re.search('nozzle_\d+_cumsum',cols)]

for c in cols:
   df[c.replace('cumsum','perc')] = df[c]/df['nozzle_sale_cumsum']
```

output:

```
   nozzle_1_cumsum  nozzle_2_cumsum  nozzle_sale_cumsum  nozzle_1_perc  nozzle_2_perc
0               10               10                  20            0.5            0.5
1               20               10                  10            2.0            1.0
2               10               10                  10            1.0            1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `axis` to `div`:

```
(df.filter(regex='nozzle_[\d+]_cumsum')
   .div(df['nozzle_sale_cumsum'], axis='rows')
   .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_cumsum','_perc'))
)
```

Output:

```
     nozzle_1_perc    nozzle_2_perc
0              0.5              0.5
1              2.0              1.0
2              1.0              1.0
```

And if you want to append these columns:

```
df.merge(the_above_code)
```

Comment: you'd then have to change all the column names and append this to the original df

Comment: df.merge as is gives error, maybe use pd.concat([df,code],axis=1)

Comment: @DerekEden for this sample data, my system doesn't give any error. Of course, `concat` works as well.

Comment: df.merge(the_above_code,left_index=True,right_index=True) works, not sure how you aren't getting an error without specifying how to merge?

Comment: @DerekEden `df.merge(right, on=None)` then uses index.

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('your csv file.csv')
data['nozzle_1_perc']=''
data['nozzle_2_perc']=''
for i in range(0,len(data)):
    data['nozzle_1_perc'][i] = data['nozzle_1_cumsum'][i]/data['nozzle_sale_cumsum'][i]
    data['nozzle_1_perc'][i] = data['nozzle_2_cumsum'][i]/data['nozzle_sale_cumsum'][i]
data
```

Comment: what if there is 100 nozzle_x_cumsum columns

Comment: to quote Raymond Hettinger "if you're indexing, you're almost certainly doing it wrong or slower"